# Awk If-Elseif-If Block

Tags: awk, gawk, csh

```
NR>NRMIN{
    if($3 == "Leu") {
        if($4 == "CD1" || $4 == "HD11" || $4 == "HD12" || $4 == "HD13") {
            next;
        }
    }
    elseif($3 == "Val") {
        if($4 == "CD1" || $4 == "HD11" || $4 == "HD12" || $4 == "HD13") {
            next;
        }
    }
    else {
        print;
    }   
}
```

I intend to selectively print lines of a space-delimited file.
Please let me know why the above code is giving an error when `gawk -f FILE_Modifier.awk NRMIN = 90 FILE > NEWFILE`

**Error Message**

```
gawk: FILE_Modifier.awk:7:     elseif($3 == "Val") {
gawk: FILE_Modifier.awk:7:                         ^ syntax error
gawk: FILE_Modifier.awk:12:     else {
gawk: FILE_Modifier.awk:12:     ^ syntax error
```

Comment: It would be very useful if you included the error message in your question instead of just telling us it `is giving an error`. Did you **really** leave spaces in the middle of the variable assignment `NRMIN = 90`? Did you **really** not leave a space between `else` and `if`?

Comment: Use two words: `else if`.  Awk doesn't support `elif` or `elsif` or variations like that.  Note that the block for `if ($3 == "Leu")` never prints anything, and similarly with the `else if ($3 == "Val")` block once you fix its syntax.  That might just be because you've minimized your code for presenting it on SO — you were working towards an MCVE ([MCVE]), or it might be an oversight.

Comment: @EdMorton Fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `elseif`. Anyway, you can rewrite the script as just:

```
awk -v nrmin=90 '(NR > nrmin) && !(($3 ~ /^(Leu|Val)$/) && ($4 ~ /^(CD1|HD11|HD12|HD13)$/))' file
```

Don't use all upper case variable names to avoid clashes with builtin names. Do set variables up front using `-v` unless you have a specific reason not to.